# Use of rank function in nested way in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

I am facing some issues with rank function when I am trying to use rank function on a select result set which is also using rank function.

**Example sql query:**

```
select a,b,c,
rank() over (partition by d order by d desc) as r_outer
from(
    select a,b,c,d from( 
                          select a,b,c,d,
                          rank() over (partition by e order by e desc) as r_inner  
                          from sample
                       )where r_inner=1
    );
```

**Problem:**

When I am using the above query, I am getting r_outer result as '1' every time although values of d are different.

**Sample Data:**

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 1 | 1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 2 | 1 |

**Expected results:**

| A | B | C | R_OUTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 2 |

**Current query results:**

| A | B | C | R_OUTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 1 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | 1 |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `partition by d order by d desc` ?  `partition by` and `order by` uses different columns mostly. (can be same column - but for rare requirements)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It seems you are overly thinking it.

Comment: Why do you expect the result you are showing? Can you explain what rule exactly you want to apply to get that number? And can you please add rows for E = 2, so we see how this affects the expected result?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  I solved this problem by not using partition by in outer sql query. I used rank() over (order by d desc) in my sql query outer rank function.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are *trying* to accomplish, but this logic:

```
rank() over (partition by d order by d desc)
```

is *always* going to return `1`.  And only `1`.  Why?  The `order by` key and `partition by` key are the same.  So, there is only one value in each partition.  And the rank of a single value is always going to be `1`.

Perhaps you intend:

```
rank() over (order by d desc)
```

However, this is really just a guess because your question has not provided enough information to know what you intend.

Comment: Thanks you. rank() over (order by d desc)  solved my problem.